# What this command (/../) means?

Tags: liferay

In liferay in my build.properties file there is a line as I copied here:

```
app.server.dir=${project.dir}/../bundles/resin-3.1.9
```

/../  what means in this statement ?

Comment: It's a directory reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means parent directory on a UNIX-based system…

Comment: the directory that contains ${project.dir}